# Merge two tables in sql by info from a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I got two tables with all sort of columns.
Lets say something like this :

Table 1 :

Model | code1 | year | type

Table 2 :

Name | code2 | serial | year

I need to merge them into a new table

Table 4 :

newModel | newName | newYear | newCode1 | newCode2 | newSerial | newType

based on info from a third table.

The third table has the following details -

```
(Table1)Code | (Table2)Code And (Table2)Serial | Year | Type 

123          | 42326 - 45622 ( xxxx-yyyy )     |2007  | Car/Truck
```

I need to match the first two tables to the details of this third table like this,

```
t1.Code = t3.Code 
AND t2.Code= t3.Code 
AND t2.Serial = t3.Serial 
AND t1.Year = t2.Year = t3.Year  
AND t1.Type = t3.Type
```

And then insert the merged data into the 4th new table which has a little different names as well. (different language).

Thanks in advance for any guidelines.

Comment: You should share your tables structures.

Comment: I added some basic table structure, hope it makes the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a `join`.  Based on what you describe, the query would look like this:

```
select t1.Model, t2.name, t1.year, t1.code1, t2.code2,
       t1.year, t2.serial, t1.type
from t3 join
     t1
     on t1.Code = t3.Code and
        t1.Year = t3.Year and
        t1.Type = t3.Type join
     t2
     on t2.Code = t3.Code and
        t2.Serial = t3.Serial and
        t2.Year = t3.Year;
```